# Print Arabic,Urdu and Hebrew in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, translation, urdu

I am using a translation api to translate text from English to others. I am just printing the translated text on the console of Eclipse. It works fine with other languages,but Arabic and Urdu. How can I print Urdu and Arabic on console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use output encoding that supports the language charcters . 
See the post "Unicode characters in the Eclipse console "
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/02/21/pro-tip-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console/